# PHPExcel showing wrong time in Datetime field

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

In my project, I am using `PHPExcel 1.8.0` for generating excel file. Everything working fine except one thing

**In one field I would like to show the `Datetime` value from the database. In database(MySql) the value is `2016-07-01 17:14:00`. But in excel it is showing as `01/07/2016 11:44`**

**Note:** The dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm format is not available by default in the library. So I added a custom format

```
const FORMAT_DATE_DATETIME2 = 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm';
```

in file **NumberFormat.php** with in `PHPExcel` Library.

An in my code I am doing like below

```
PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel(strtotime($det["filed_with_timestamp"]));//converting timestamp to ``PHPExcel format

$this -> excel_180 -> getActiveSheet() -> getStyle('O2:O' . $this -> excel_180 -> getActiveSheet() -> getHighestDataRow()) -> getNumberFormat() -> setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DATETIME2);//assigning formatting to the columns.
```

In documentation I found that the `hh:mm` format in `PHPExcel` will treat like 24 hour time format. Then why it is showing wrong in my excel file?

Am I missing something? Please help. Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: @CBroe, There are some formats for the time in PHPExcel like h:mm, h:mm:ss, etc. It always shows wrong value only. I already checked with them and all. After that I created a custom format

Comment: I think it may have something to do with timezones. `strtotime` converts a string into a UTC timestamp, then if your timezone is offset from UTC it will change respectively.

Comment: @ImClarky, Thanks for the clue. I changed the offset to UTC and it worked.